# SELECT date in Mysql Returning wrong data

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to generate a report, but It's returning incorret data. I'm trying to search informations between two different dates.

```
$data1 = '21/02/2019 03:46';
$data2 = '16/08/2019 03:46';

$data1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $data1)->format('Y-m-d');
$data2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $data2)->format('Y-m-d');

 echo $data1;

$sql = "
SELECT p.pedido_id 
     , p.pedido_status
     , STR_TO_DATE(p.pedido_data,'%d/%m/%Y') as pedido_data
     , l.lista_pedido
     , l.lista_item as item_id
     , l.lista_title as item_title
     , SUM(l.lista_qtde) as total 
  FROM pedido p
  JOIN lista l
    ON lista_pedido = pedido_id 
 WHERE pedido_status = 3 
   AND (pedido_data >= $data1 AND pedido_data <= $data2) 
 GROUP by item_id;
 ";


$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

When it appears the result, it brings results from other dates either.

This is the table of Results:

```
253 Fio de Malha - Marfim   2018-12-08
254 Fio de Malha - Areia    2018-12-07
257 Kit Clutch alça corrente Pérola 2019-02-18
258 Alça corrente Acrílica - Branca 2019-02-18
259 Alça corrente Acrílica - Preta  2019-02-18
261 Alça corrente Acrílica - Goiaba 2019-02-19
262 Alça corrente Acrílica - Vermelha   2019-02-24
263 Alça corrente Acrílica - Marrom 2019-02-26
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me to solve this issue. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Where you're going wrong is not storing dates as dates.

Comment: You are missing the single quotes around the date literals in sql (should be `pedido_data >= '$data1'`. But it would be better if you used prepared statements with parameters and not string interpolation. That group by item_id at the end of the statement does not look good either. Your statement is most likely against the SQL standard.

Comment: You're trying to search between dates using dictionary (lexicographical) sort. That makes little sense in general but it totally fails when using D/M/Y as format.

Comment: Thanks for being gentle with me @Shadow I can be a dipstick sometimes

Comment: @RiggsFolly I missed it as well :)

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Depending on what strict modes MySQL has enabled on a server you might fall foul with that query of MySQLs GROUP BY strict mode (https://gabi.dev/2016/03/03/group-by-are-you-sure-you-know-it/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this part of your `WHERE` clause:

```
AND (pedido_data >= $data1 AND pedido_data <= $data2)
```

Since you cannot access aliases in the `WHERE` clause, MySQL is using your original date column value in this test, and so the comparison is happening as text instead of as a date. You need to change this line to

```
AND STR_TO_DATE(p.pedido_data,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '$data1' AND '$data2'
```

Note also the addition of quotes around the `$data1` and `$data2` values (otherwise `2019-02-28` gets interpreted literally as 1989).

Note that if you had named your alias something other than the same name as the column you would have received a MySQL error message on the `WHERE` clause when trying to execute the query which would have shown the problem immediately.